# Find instagram page from direct image url

Tags: instagram, reverse-engineering

Does anyone know how to reverse find an image from instagram?
For example, here is a link I know is from cnn instagram, but I want to know how to find it if I didn't know that. [link](https://instagram.fwlg1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t51.2885-15/e35/19985320_1489967767727981_5255599038840963072_n.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know yet is the "search by image" with google. Like this : https://assets.pcmag.com/media/images/480874-google-search-by-image.jpg?thumb=y&width=810&height=456

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried that method, it doesn't work with instagram photos